# iOS размер webView не совпадает с экраном

Tags: ios, webview, view

На более старых айфонах всё как надо. На iphone Xr (реальном)  и на  айфон 11 (в эмуляторе) webView меньше чем размер экрана. (приложение делалось ещё для старых айфонов).
Если в Main.storyboard выбрать View as: iPhone 11, и растянуть руками вебвью на весь экран - работает нормально. Но тогда на старых айфонах сдвигается вправо и не входит в экран.

Как сделать чтобы было на любом устройстве одинаково на весь экран? Так понимаю, выставляются сейчас фиксированные размеры. А как то можно задать просто 100% ширина и высота? (типа match_parent в андроиде)

Answer (score 0):

Изучите и применяйте [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html). Если кратко, вам нужно с помощью 4 constraints прикрепить стороны вашего вью к сторонам его супервью (родителю)